# Solve the differential equation $x''-x=0$ with conditions $x(0)=1,x'(0)=-1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $x''-x=0$ with conditions $x(0)=1,x'(0)=-1$.

What I tried:

Let $x=\mathit{e}^{\gamma t}$, $c_{1}=1$, and $c_{2}=-1$.

$(\mathit{e}^{\gamma t})''-\mathit{e}^{\gamma t}=\mathit{e}^{\gamma t}(\gamma ^{2}-1)=0$

$\gamma = \pm 1$, so let $\gamma_{1}=-1$, $\gamma_{2}=1$.

$x(t)=c_{1}\mathit{e}^{\gamma_{1} t}+c_{2}\mathit{e}^{\gamma_{2} t}=\mathit{e}^{- t}-\mathit{e}^{ t}$

However, according to Symbolab, the answer is $\mathit{e}^{- t}$.

So what did I do wrong? Did I set the wrong values?

Comment: Your general solution is correct, but you didn't use the initial values properly. Setting the $c$'s in the beginning is nonsense, BTW. You find the $c$'s by using the initial values.

Comment: I am not really taught how to solve second order equations, I just used this general form I found online, and so please explain how to use the initial values properly.

Comment: The solution is given by $$x(t)=e^{-t}$$

Comment: Your general solution to the ODE is $x(t) = c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^t$. Now put in the initial values. That's very simple.

Comment: Now yes, it was a typo, sorry.

Comment: @amsmath I am not sure about how to do this part though, because I don't know what $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ stand for.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Whatever. OP wrote that already in the question.

Comment: @numericalorange $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants that are unknowns. For any value that you assign to them the function $c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^t$ will be a solution of the differential equation. But you don't only have the differential equation, you also have the two conditions $x(0) = 1$ and $x'(0)=-1$. Now, if $x(t) = c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^t$, what is $x(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is correct. 
$$x(t)=c_1 e^{\gamma_1 t}+ c_2 e^{\gamma_2 t} = c_1 e^{-t} + c_2 e^{t}$$
The general solution is not a solution but rather a family of solutions to the differential equation. The initial conditions will determine the constant terms $c_1$ and $c_2$.
When you plug in $t=0$, you get:
$$x(0) = c_1 + c_2 = 1$$
and when you differentiate your solution and plug in $t=0$, you get:
$$x'(0) = -c_1 + c_2 = -1$$
Hopefully you can carry on from here.